# Modify instance from @RequestBody before JSR-303 validation is executed?

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I am using `JSR-303` validation in my Spring Boot application. Application acts as a REST API.

This is an example how I use `@Validated` annotation with validation groups:

```
 @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<APIResponse> add(@RequestBody @Validated(Schedule.Insert.class) Schedule schedule) {

        Assert.notNull(schedule);

        schedule.setUser(getCurrentUser());

        try {

            Schedule newSchedule = scheduleService.save(schedule);

            APIResponse response = new APIResponse(HttpStatus.CREATED);
            response.data("schedule", newSchedule);

            return APIResponse.export(response);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new RequestProcessingAPIException("", e);

        }
}
```

I'm looking for a way how to "inject" a particular user object (`schedule.setUser(getCurrentUser());`) into Schedule instance from request body before validation process is executed.

Why? Because I have this field in `Schedule` bean and must not be null.

```
@NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```

In this situation validation produces errors because `User` object is not already known.

Is there some way how to inject `User` instance into `@RequestBody` object **before** validation is executed?